# Writing custom IEnumerator<T> with iterators

Tags: c#, iterator

How can I write a custom `IEnumerator<T>` implementation which needs to maintain some state and still get to use iterator blocks to simplify it? The best I can come up with is something like this:

```
public class MyEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T> {
    private IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;
    public int Position {get; private set;} // or some other custom properties

    public MyEnumerator() {
        Position = 0;
        _enumerator = MakeEnumerator();
    }

    private IEnumerator<T> MakeEnumerator() {
        // yield return something depending on Position
    } 

    public bool MoveNext() {
        bool res = _enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (res) Position++;
        return res;
    }

    // delegate Reset and Current to _enumerator as well
}

public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> {

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public MyEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return new MyEnumerator<T>();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Why do you want to write an iterator class? The whole point of an iterator block is so you don't have to...

i.e.

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    int position = 0; // state
    while(whatever) {
        position++;
        yield return ...something...;
    }
}
```

If you add more context (i,e, why the above can't work), we can probably help more.

But if possible, avoid writing an iterator class. They are lots of work, and easy to get wrong.

By the way, you don't really have to bother with `Reset` - it is largely deprecated, and shouldn't really ever be used (since it can't be relied to work for an arbitrary enumerator).

If you want to consume an inner iterator, that is fine too:

```
int position = 0;
foreach(var item in source) {
   position++;
   yield return position;
}
```

or if you only have an enumerator:

```
while(iter.MoveNext()) {
   position++;
   yield return iter.Current;
}
```

You might also consider adding the state (as a tuple) to the thing you yield:

```
class MyState<T> {
    public int Position {get;private set;}
    public T Current {get;private set;}
    public MyState(int position, T current) {...} // assign
}
...
yield return new MyState<Foo>(position, item);
```

Finally, you could use a LINQ-style extension/delegate approach, with an `Action<int,T>` to supply the position and value to the caller:

```
    static void Main() {
        var values = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        values.ForEach((pos, s) => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pos, s));            
    }
    static void ForEach<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> source,
            Action<int, T> action) {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        int position = 0;
        foreach (T item in source) {
            action(position++, item);
        }
    }
```

Outputs:

```
0: a
1: b
2: c
```

Comment: I'm looking at the case of the internal enumerator "while(iter.MoveNext()) ... [etc]": aren't we leaking the 'iter' instance here ? The auto-generated outer enumerator wouldn't know 'iter' should be disposed, right ?

Comment: @toong if your iterator block takes out something IDisposable, then it should use a `using` statement - which will then be correctly cleaned up under most normal usage,

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to concur with Marc here. Either write an enumerator class completely yourself if you really want to (just because you can?) or simply use an interator block and yield statements and be done with it. Personally, I'm never touching enumerator classes again. ;-)

Comment: As I said, I really _don't_ want to :)

Comment: Most people who are looking for this is to understand better. I have been asked to do this for programming test in applications. Just a FYI.

Answer (score 1):

@Marc Gravell

> But if possible, avoid writing an iterator class. They are lots of work, and easy to get wrong.

That's precisely why I want to use `yield` machinery inside my iterator, to do the heavy lifting.

> You might also consider adding the state (as a tuple) to the thing you yield:

Yes, that works. However, it's an extra allocation at each and every step. If I am interested only in `T` at most steps, that's an overhead I don't need if I can avoid it.

However, your last suggestion gave me an idea:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(Action<T, int> action) {
    int position = 0; // state
    while(whatever) {
        position++;
        var t = ...something...;
        action(t, position);
        yield return t;
    }
}

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator(DoNothing<T, int>());
}
```

Comment: Intersting - a lazy version of ForEach; it does duplicate the T, of course (once in the yield, once in the action/invoke), but interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I made a pretty simple Iterator that borrows the default Enumerator to do most (really all) of the work.  The constructor takes an `IEnumerator<T>` and my implementation simply hands it the work.  I've added an `Index` field to my custom Iterator.

I made a simple example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0iGmVz

To use this Iterator setup you would have something like this in your custom Collection/List class:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>{
    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(){
        return new IndexedEnumerator<T>(base.GetEnumerator());
    }
}
```

Now `foreach` and other built-in functions will get your custom enumerator, and any behavior you don't want to override will use the normal implementation.

```
public static class Helpers{
    //Extension method to get the IndexEnumerator
    public static IndexedEnumerator<T> GetIndexedEnumerator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list){
        return new IndexedEnumerator<T>(list.GetEnumerator());
    }
}

//base Enumerator methods/implementation
public class BaseEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>{
    public BaseEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumer){
        enumerator = enumer;
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerator<T> enumerator{get;set;}

    protected virtual T current {get;set;}

    public virtual bool MoveNext(){
        return enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(){
        return enumerator;
    }

    public virtual T Current {get{return enumerator.Current;}}

    object IEnumerator.Current {get{return enumerator.Current;}}

    public virtual void Reset(){}

    public virtual void Dispose(){}
}

public class IndexedEnumerator<T> : BaseEnumerator<T>
{
    public IndexedEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumer):base(enumer){}

    public int Index {get; private set;}

    public override bool MoveNext(){
        Index++;
        return enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```